# How do I return a non-movable (but copyable) object?

Tags: c++, move

Edit: End goal:  I want to make a container class that never uses move, even when it's available. NonMove is a class of test objects for that container.

I tried different variations, but GCC insists on wanting to use move.

```
class NonMove {
 public:
  NonMove() {}

  // Copy.
  NonMove(const NonMove&) {}
  NonMove& operator=(const NonMove&) {}

  // Move
  NonMove(NonMove&&) = delete;
  NonMove& operator=(NonMove&&) = delete;
};

NonMove foo() {
  return NonMove();
}
```

Error with GCC 4.9.1 with -std=gnu++11

```
move.cc: In function ‘NonMove foo()’:
move.cc:15:18: error: use of deleted function ‘NonMove::NonMove(NonMove&&)’
   return NonMove();
                  ^
move.cc:10:3: note: declared here
   NonMove(NonMove&&) = delete;
   ^
```

Comment: Explicitly deleted move constructors participate in overload resolution. If you want it to be copied and not moved, declare the copy ctor, don't declare the move ctor, and no move ctor will be generated. Ditto for `operator=`.

Comment: Remove `NonMove(NonMove&&) = delete;`, the class will be non-movable-copyable anyway.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for deleting the move operations? Declaring a copy constructor or assignment operator will prevent them from being generated, without introducing any unwanted overloads. (In other words, the class will be movable, with movement the same as copying. Your class is completely unmovable, hence the failure to move it when required.)

Comment: Overload resolution does not fail. It finds `NonMove(NonMove&&)`. The compiler selects `NonMove(NonMove&&)`. `NonMove(NonMove&&)` is deleted. The compiler rejects the program.

Comment: T.C: but why does it participate in overload resolution? Sure, I can implement the move ctor as invoking copy ctor, and same for move assign, but why doesn't deleting it do that? This is a test class for ensuring that another template works with non-movable objects.

Comment: OP clarify which standard you want compatibility with. It's not clear why you delete the move operators "and build with -std=gnu++03", just deleting the move operators is sufficient. (I assume that "delete" here means you delete their text from your source, as opposed to defining as deleted)

Comment: @Thomas if you want moves to behave just like copies, **do nothing**. `= delete` exists to forbid things, not to give them default behaviour.

Comment: @RMartinhoFernandes He is trying to forbid moving

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yet they say "Sure, I can implement the move ctor as invoking copy ctor, and same for move assign, but why doesn't deleting it do that?"

Comment: This does seem a bit broken though - if you need to avoid `= delete` to get the copy constructor used here, what will stop the move constructor being used elsewhere?

Comment: @TonyD Um, if you don't declare the move ctor here, there will be no move constructor for this class.

Comment: `NonMove(NonMove&&) = delete;` means "if I ever attempt to construct a `NonMove` from a `NonMove` rvalue, scream at me".

Comment: @TonyD huh? If there is no move constructor (the correct solution) then the move constructor cannot be used elsewhere.

Comment: @T.C. so there's never an implicitly generated move constructor?  I must admit my C++11 is pretty ad hoc as I've not been able to use it with the old compilers used on my professional projects. but I'd assumed that the `= delete` inhibited such an implicit compiler-generated move constructor (even if that amounted to doing copies where necessary and moves where supported for member variables/bases)....

Comment: Contex: I'm only interested in C++11. My actual end goal is that I want to create a container class that never uses moving, even when it's available.

Comment: @TonyD except for one particular exception for backward compatibility (which is marked as deprecated behaviour), declaring any of those special members prevents generation of the others.

Comment: @Thomas Please make that clear in the question.

Comment: Your edit says "never uses copy" which is not what you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> End goal: I want to make a container class that never uses [move], even when it's available. NonMove is a class of test objects for that container.

Your class does not necessarily help achieve your goal, because deleting the move constructor means the type is not CopyConstructible, so cannot be used to accurately test a container that only copies.

To prevent moving you can ensure that all potential copies or moves are done with a const source object:

```
NonMove foo() {
  return const_cast<const NonMove&&>(NonMove());
}
```

The move constructor isn't viable if the RHS is `const`.

It's usually sufficient to just ensure the RHS is an lvalue, as that won't be moved either, but there is a special case for function return values, which can be moved even if they are lvalues, meaning this would try to use the move constructor if it exists:

```
NonMove foo() {
  NonMove nm;
  return nm;
}
```

Adding `const` ensures it will be copied instead:

```
NonMove foo() {
  NonMove nm;
  return const_cast<const NonMove&>(nm);
}
```